# Negative marking with google forms

Tags: google-forms

My entire school is using google forms to create quizes for students. I am making a project that incorporates making quizes for other students. Because I would like to be consistent I made them with google forms.

I would like to add points for right answer, 0 points for no answer (no question is mandatory, so students can skip it) and give negative points when their answer is wrong. The test would start with some amount of +points, which would make sure that if a student answers everything wrong, he will get 0 points, not negative amount of points.

But I face a problem, because google forms do not allow negative marking. **Is there a way to add negative marking to google forms?** It has to be automatic - that means it should recognize which answers are right based on form data. I have seen add-ons like flubaroo, which allow you to write IF statement for every answer and if it is right add points and if it is wrong, remove points. I do NOT want anything like that. It has to be automatic.